# Nx 13 Migration failure: update-tasks-runner

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

**Background**
I have moved my Angular apps from 12 to 13.3.11.

**What**
When running `nx migrate 13.10.6` a `migrations.json` file is generated as expected.However, when running the migrations, it fails on the step "13-10-0-update-tasks-runner".

I get the following errors from Nx:

- `Failed to run 13-10-0-update-tasks-runner from @nrwl/workspace. This workspace is NOT up to date!`
- `Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`

**Question**
What am I doing wrong, and/or how do I resolve this issue?

**Stack trace:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
> at updateTasksRunner (C:\Users\SD829695\Workspace\Payviewer UI\sdworx-workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\src\migrations\update-13-10-0\update-tasks-runner.js:7:83)
> at C:\Users\SD829695\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-22332-q4v32FBBq7aD\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\migrate.js:758:15
> at Generator.next ()
> at C:\Users\SD829695\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-22332-q4v32FBBq7aD\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:118:75
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\SD829695\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-22332-q4v32FBBq7aD\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:16)
> at runNxMigration (C:\Users\SD829695\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-22332-q4v32FBBq7aD\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\migrate.js:737:20)
> at C:\Users\SD829695\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-22332-q4v32FBBq7aD\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\migrate.js:631:43
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (C:\Users\SD829695\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-22332-q4v32FBBq7aD\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:115:62)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is an issue with the migration scripts from Nx; they require you to have `tasksRunnerOptions` present in your `nx.json` file. So, I did that and was now able to run the migrations successfully. Apparently, this is an issue even in the 14.*.* migrations so I will leave it there until I see it is solved.

[image]

Full details of where I found the fix are in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10010

Comment: omg.. life saver!